# Combining two ggplot scatterplots with transects as origins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I work as a forestry tech for a state park and my boss is interested in finding new ways to map our forestry plots. We collected data on trees in a 0.6 acre square (all plot boundaries are 49.2m). We collected tree location data from TWO horizontal transects, one at 10.1m, and one at 39.1m, both running south to north.

We collected the data this way because it is difficult to see all of the trees in the plot from one transect. So, I have x,y data for some tree locations from transect 1, some from transect 2, and some from both transects to compare accuracy.

X is the distance along the transect and Y is the distance to the tree, all at right angles. If the tree was west of the transect, it had a negative Y value, if it was east, it was positive. You see why I can't combine the data into one dataset?

I am able to graph two plots the way I want them (below script), but I need to get them on the same graph so I can compare those trees that were measured from both transect 1 and transect 2. I don't know how to do this, since the transects need to be two different origins.

How can I overlay two `ggplot` scatterplots with transects shown? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have read through all the related posts and haven't found anything that has worked. There was an interesting post using geom_step but I wasn't able to figure it out with my current code. I need to keep the aes() line as is (I think) so that the points show up as representations of tree DBH.

```
p1<-ggplot(trans1, aes(x=Transect.1.Distance.from, 
y=Transect.1.Distance.Along)) + 
  geom_point(colour="red",aes(size=DBHcm))
p2<-p1 + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
p2
p3<-ggplot(trans2, aes(x=Transect.2.Distance.from, 
y=Transect.2.Distance.along)) + 
  geom_point(colour="black",aes(size=DBHcm))
p4<-p3+geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
p4
```

I tried just do something stupid like ggplot(p2+p4) but the error message says

> "Error: Don't know how to add p4 to a plot"

Here is some sample data from my dataset from transect 1 and 2:

```
Tree ID Species DBHcm   Cut Transect1.Distance.from Transect1.Distance.Along
336 PSMEM   34.60   No  9.4 -6.3
408 SESE3   50.70   Yes 3.5 -2.7
337 PSMEM   36.30   Yes 9.6 -3.2
409 SESE3   48.10   Yes 5.4 3.6
338 PSMEM   19.00   Yes 13.7    -4.8
410 PSMEM   30.90   No  10  1.7
339 PSMEM   28.50   Yes 13.6    -7.8

Tree ID Species DBHcm   Cut Transect2.Distance.from Transect2.Distance.along
446 PSMEM   24.50   Yes 44.3    -10.1
379 SESE3   23.10   No  50  -11
447 PSMEM   32.30   No  40.2    -8.8
380 PSMEM   22.10   No  51.5    -10.4
381 PSMEM   29.20   No  48.8    -7.3
448 PSMEM   42.80   No  39.3    -4.8
382 PSMEM   18.70   No  46.6    -6.4
449 PSMEM   24.00   No  43  -5.8
383 SESE3   12.60   No  48.1    -7.3
385 SESE3   28.00   No  51.8    -7.3
```

Here's the plot I got when I ran your suggested code, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr3j1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start. If it does work, please provide some data for testing.

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = trans1, aes(x=Transect.1.Distance.from, 
                       y=Transect.1.Distance.Along, size=DBHcm), colour="red") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  geom_point(data = trans2, aes(x=Transect.2.Distance.from, 
                       y=Transect.2.Distance.along, size=DBHcm), color = "black")  

p
```

With the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)
trans1 <- tribble(
  ~TreeID, ~Species, ~DBHcm, ~Cut,  ~Transect1.Distance.from, ~Transect1.Distance.Along, 
  336, "PSMEM",   34.60,   "No",  9.4, -6.3,
  408, "SESE3",   50.70,   "Yes", 3.5, -2.7,
  337, "PSMEM",   36.30,   "Yes", 9.6, -3.2,
  409, "SESE3",   48.10,   "Yes", 5.4,  3.6,
  338, "PSMEM",   19.00,   "Yes", 13.7, -4.8,
  410, "PSMEM",   30.90,   "No",  10,  1.7,
  339, "PSMEM",   28.50,   "Yes", 13.6, -7.8
)

trans2 <- tribble(
  ~TreeID, ~Species, ~DBHcm, ~Cut,  ~Transect2.Distance.from, ~Transect2.Distance.Along,
  446, "PSMEM",   24.50,   "Yes", 44.3,    -10.1,
  379, "SESE3",   23.10,   "No",  50,  -11,
  447, "PSMEM",   32.30,   "No",  40.2,    -8.8,
  380, "PSMEM",   22.10,   "No",  51.5,    -10.4,
  381, "PSMEM",   29.20,   "No",  48.8,    -7.3,
  448, "PSMEM",   42.80,   "No",  39.3,    -4.8,
  382, "PSMEM",   18.70,   "No",  46.6,    -6.4,
  449, "PSMEM",   24.00,   "No",  43,  -5.8,
  383, "SESE3",   12.60,   "No",  48.1,    -7.3,
  385, "SESE3",   28.00,   "No",  51.8,    -7.3
)
```

And the same code:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = trans1, aes(x=Transect1.Distance.from, 
                                y=Transect1.Distance.Along, size=DBHcm), colour="red") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  geom_point(data = trans2, aes(x=Transect2.Distance.from, 
                                y=Transect2.Distance.Along, size=DBHcm), color = "black")  

p
```

[image]

Comment: It works beautifully! However I am concerned it may not be accurate, with the two-transect thing. Where in the code does it tell R to use the transects as the origins? I have added some sample data to my original question. It would also be wonderful to add labels using the species column to check the trees are in the right place (for example I know we mapped one tanoak tree from both transects and its the only tanoak in the plot). THANK YOU R GODS AND GODDESSES

Comment: I'm just a struggling new user. Adding labels is a little tricky. You can try to look at things like `label = Species`,  `geom_text()`, `geom_label`, or `ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Species))`. You may attract a good solution for that if you post a specific question about it.